# Is it correct to use "work" instead of "work place" in "I went to my sister's work today"?

Tags: word-choice

> 1. I went to my sister's **work** today.
> 2. I went to my sister's **work place** today.

Which of the above sentences should I use? Do I have to use the second one?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. One of the expectations here is that you demonstrate your initial research; for example, looking up *[work](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/work_2#work_2__12)* in Macmillan turns up the meaning *3. [uncountable] a place where someone goes to do their job*, as does [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/work), *Work is the place where you do your job.* If the dictionary definition is not sufficient, please [edit] your post to explain why, I strongly encourage you to take the [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Suppose your sister is carving a big statue. That is her work, so you can go to her work. Now suppose your sister is researching ideas. You can't go to her work. But in both cases you can go to her place of work.

Comment: probably office, aka place of work [very formal]

Comment: @choster, Vickifred's question is actually quite subtle, and I doubt if a dictionary on its own could provide an explanation of why the first sentence sounds wrong.

Comment: @javalatte The first sentence isn't wrong, and I actually disagree with your answer. It might be informal, but it is quite unexceptional at least in North America, and based on the sample sentences I had assumed this was also the case elsewhere. *They're putting in a new carpet at my work.* *He left it at his work.* I wouldn't use it in business communication or really must writing in general, but we used it all the time growing up and no one has objected it in my adult life on the opposite coast.

Comment: @choster: we expect the OP to cite references. Could you please also cite references for your sample sentences? Maybe it's a North American thing , but none of the twenty or so examples in th Cambridge  and Oxford Dictionaries look like this.

Comment: They're not hard to find with a simple web search, mostly in forum posts which is not surprising because as I note this is a conversational shorthand for what I might write out as *work site* or *workplace*. See e.g. https://twitter.com/heardatmywork, [at his work](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/politics/9987374/Chuka-Umunnas-Wikipedia-entry-edited-from-computer-at-his-work.html)

Comment: ... [to her work](https://www.proflowers.com/blog/should-I-send-flowers-to-her-work) and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

[Work](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/work) can mean an activity, a place or several other things. If we assign ownership to **work**, for example "my work", we are generally talking about an activity, not a place. If we want to talk about a place of work, we never assign ownership: it is assumed that we are talking about the place of work of the person we just mentioned.

> I went to work today - *my place of work*
>   She went to work today - *her place of work*

So if you say "my sister's work" I would assume that you were talking about the activity that she does, and going there doesn't sound right. You can make your sentence sound right by saying

> I went to see my sister at work today

Here, work isn't assigned an owner, so it's ok to mean a place of work. Your sister was the last person mentioned, so it's her place of work.

The second sentence is correct but **work place** quite formal. As Lambie has suggested, you could say **office** or **school** rather than work place.

Answer (score 1):

I went to her place of work is the norm in English. Workplace is acceptable.

I went to her work is wrong. I think they say this in America. Also, I went to her job (you hear this a lot on trashy American shows).
Work and job are not physical places - you cannot go to them.